# How to allow dead_code and unused_imports for dev builds only?

Tags: rust, compiler-warnings

The unused imports and dead code warnings are the most common that I've found while learning Rust, and they get annoying after awhile (a very short while, like a few seconds). Especially when they are mixed with compiler errors, because it makes the console difficult to read.

I was able to turn off these warnings:

```rust
#![allow(unused_imports)]
#![allow(dead_code)]
```

This will disable the warnings for all builds, but I want the warnings enabled for release builds.

I tried disabling them like this:

```rust
#![cfg(dev)]
#![allow(unused_imports)]
#![allow(dead_code)]
```

But, this removed the entire Rust file from release builds (not what I want).

I tried to configure using `cfg_attr` but it had no effect for either builds.

```rust
#![cfg_attr(dev, allow(unused_imports))]
#![cfg_attr(dev, allow(dead_code))]
```

I have Googled and read all the related questions on StackOverflow but can't figure this out.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`dev` isn't a supported predicate for conditional compilation, so your examples will never include the affected code. As far as I know, the best way to detect debug mode is instead with `#[cfg(debug_assertions)]`. With my testing, `#![cfg_attr(debug_assertions, allow(dead_code, unused_imports))]` seems to work to disable the lints for debug builds but enable them in release builds.

You can see a list of supported predicates [in the Rust reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html).